# Forin loop in different browsers javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome, firefox

I'm testing the `for...in` loop in javascript like this:

```js
let test = ["hello"];

for (let index in test) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

With this example, in Chromium this prints something like this:

[image: Chromium result 1]

And in Firefox and Chrome the result is this:

[image: Firefox and Chrome result 2]

Can someone explain why get different outputs in this case?

Comment: In Chrome, I get your purported firefox result.

Comment: you are right, editing question, is in chromium xD

Comment: [Why is using “for…in” for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504) although you *shouldn't* be getting this in Chrome. It seems like something on the page (or an extension) is changing the array prototype and exposing the exact problem the other Q&A shows. Although, given the names printed, it seems you're iterating over a Lodash wrapper or a similar library.

Comment: \*tsk tsk\* it seems it's our old friend (well, not really), [Prototype](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_enum_ingroupsof.htm) given the existence of an `inGroupsOf` method on the array.

Comment: Don't use for...in with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be that the page where you're trying this uncludes the [Prototype framework](http://prototypejs.org/). It has a very old school approach by enhancing the native prototypes in JavaScript to provide convenience methods.

```js
let test = ["hello"];

for (let index in test) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js" integrity="sha512-C4LuwXQtQOF1iTRy3zwClYLsLgFLlG8nCV5dCxDjPcWsyFelQXzi3efHRjptsOzbHwwnXC3ZU+sWUh1gmxaTBA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This prints

```
0
each
eachSlice
all
any
collect
detect
findAll
select
grep
include
member
inGroupsOf
inject
invoke
max
min
partition
pluck
reject
sortBy
toArray
zip
size
inspect
_reverse
_each
clear
first
last
compact
flatten
without
uniq
intersect
clone
```

Compare with iterating over a normal un-enhanced array:

```js
let test = ["hello"];

for (let index in test) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

This prints

```
0
```

The practice of changing the native prototypes has since become a frowned upon

- partly for the reason you see here - you get a lot more results than you need or expect. Also relevant is [Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)
- another reason is that it can clash with future enhancements of native prototypes. This showed up as a real problem back when the ES6 draft wanted to include a `String#contains` and `Array#contains` methods but [the MooTools library already implemented them and thus lead to a breaking change](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2402) ([see also on ESDiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible)). The methods had to be renamed to the less intuitive [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)